# What is the time complexity of Ruby's built in #permutation and #repeated_permutation methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, permutation

I've been wondering about the time complexity of some of Ruby's built-in methods, these two in particular.  I think the best I've been able to come up with for a permutation method on my own is Θ(n · n!), does Ruby's built-in perform better?  If so, please help me understand their algorithm.

Comment: [This for `repeated_permutation`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L5218) and [this for `permutation`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L4979) (more context for `permutation` [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L5081)) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Permutation

[`Array#permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) returns an Enumerator with `n!` Arrays, so the time complexity will be at least `O(n!)`.

I wrote this method :

```
def slow_method(n)
  (1..n).to_a.permutation.each do |p|
    p
  end
end
```

It doesn't do anything with `p`, expect forcing the generation of all the permutations. Building an Array of all the permutations would use too much memory.

This method was called 10 times for n between 10 and 13, and the average times in seconds were :

```
t10 = 0.618895
t11 = 6.7815425
t12 = 82.896605
t13 = 1073.015602
```

`O(n!)` looks like a reasonable approximation :

```
t13/fact(13)*fact(12)/t12 #=> 0.995694114280165
t13/fact(13)*fact(11)/t11 #=> 1.0142685297667369
t13/fact(13)*fact(10)/t10 #=> 1.0103498450722133
```

`O(n*n!)` doesn't :

```
t13/(fact(13)*13)*fact(12)*12/t12 #=> 0.9191022593355369
t13/(fact(13)*13)*fact(11)*11/t11 #=> 0.8582272174949312
t13/(fact(13)*13)*fact(10)*10/t10 #=> 0.777192188517087
```

The generation seems to be `O(n!)`, but doing anything with the generated Arrays would bring the overall complexity to `O(n*n!)`.

Why isn't the generation `O(n*n!)`? It could come from the fact that when recursively generating `[1,2,3,4,5].permutation`, the remaining permutations are the same for `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`.

`O(n!)` is already so slow that `n` will never be much bigger than 10, so `O(n*n!)` isn't much worse. For `n=20`, `n!` is `2432902008176640000` and `n*n!` is `48658040163532800000`.

## Repeated Permutation

`[1,2,...n].repeated_permutation(k)` generates `n**k` Arrays of k elements.

The complexity should be either `O(n**k)` or `O(k*n**k)`.

For `k=n`, it becomes `O(n**n)` or `O(n**(n+1))`, which is even (much) worse than for `permutation`.

Comment: Kudos for measuring the time! But you did not answer their second question, which is how the Ruby algorithm works.

Comment: How nice of you to write "Kudos" but still downvote my answer. Why exactly? Half an answer is still better than none at all. I wrote this answer after 3 months of inactivity, even though it seemed to interest a few people.

Answer (score 0):

There are algorithms to iteratively generate all permutations of a list.

How? The algorithm generates all permutations of `[1,2,3,4,...,n]` in lexicographic order. Given one permutation the algorithm generates the next lexicographic permutation in `O(1)` time.

These are the steps

- Find the largest index `k` such that `a[k] < a[k + 1]`, if no such index exists the permutation is the last permutation
- Find the largest index `l` greater than `k` such that `a[k] < a[l]`
- Swap the value of `a[k]` with that of `a[l]`
- Reverse the sequence from `a[k + 1]` up to and including the final element `a[n]`

What is the complexity?

Each step is `O(1)` and there are `O(n!)` permutations, so the total complexity is `O(n!)`.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 look like `O(n)`. Could you please explain why every step is O(1)?